# TTRequestLoader max content size issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I'm getting these errors when trying to load big files using TTRequestLoader:

```
2011-06-30 07:25:21.782 xxxxxxx[1261:607] -[TTRequestLoader connection:didReceiveResponse:](317):
 TTDASSERT failed: 0 == _queue.maxContentLength || contentLength <=_queue.maxContentLength
```

Is there a function to increase the size of the files loaded by TTURLRequest, in order to aviod these errors?

My code:

```
TTURLRequest* request = [TTURLRequest
                       requestWithURL: [_url absoluteString]
                       delegate: self];

request.cachePolicy = cachePolicy;
request.cacheExpirationAge = (60*60*24*3);

TTURLDataResponse* response = [[TTURLDataResponse alloc] init];
request.response = response;
TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(response);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assertion has the following [comment](https://github.com/buddydvd/three20/blob/master/src/Three20Network/Sources/TTRequestLoader.m#L284) above it:

```
// If you hit this assertion it's because a massive file is about to be downloaded.
// If you're sure you want to do this, add the following line to your app delegate startup
// method. Setting the max content length to zero allows anything to go through. If you just
// want to raise the limit, set it to any positive byte size.
// [[TTURLRequestQueue mainQueue] setMaxContentLength:0]
```

So calling `[[TTURLRequestQueue mainQueue] setMaxContentLength:0]` should do it.